# Deleting a type in Elastic Search using curl

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to delete a type in elastic search using curl script in bat file

```
ECHO Running Curl Script
curl -XDELETE "http://localhost/testing/" -d''
pause
```

The response that i got was No handler found for uri . I looked into documentation of Elastic Search and it says to use delete by query `https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/docs-delete-by-query.html`

How can i modify the my curl script to use this new api for ES 2.3

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the delete-by-query API to delete all documents of a given type, you can do it like this:

```
curl -XDELETE "http://localhost/testing/_query?q=_type:typename"
```

However, you're better off deleting the index and recreating it so you can modify the mapping type as you see fit.

```
curl -XDELETE "http://localhost/testing/"
curl -XPUT "http://localhost/testing/" -d '{"settings": {...}, "mappings": {...}}'
```

Comment: tried using curl -XDELETE "http://localhost/testing/_query?q=_type:book" but still getting the same error  where testing is the indexname amd book is the typename

Comment: Have you installed the delete-by-query plugin? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.3/plugins-delete-by-query.html

Comment: Great to hear!!